# Design pattern to build one or more side-by-side views

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I am attempting to build a dynamic control in Android that uses the builder pattern to construct a view that looks like:

[** Text][** Text]

Essentially, I am looking to create a view with an image and some text and group multiple such views together.

```
public static class DualBuilder {
        private final Context mContext;
        protected Drawable mFirstButtonIcon;
        protected Drawable mSecondButtonIcon;
        protected String mFirstButtonText;
        protected String mSecondButtonText;

        private DualBuilder(@NonNull final Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public DualBuilder firstButtonIcon(@Nullable final Drawable firstButtonIcon) {
            super.buttonIcon(firstButtonIcon);
            return this;
        }

        public DualBuilder firstButtonText(@NonNull final String firstButtonText) {
            super.buttonPrimaryText(firstButtonText);
            return this;
        }

        public DualBuilder secondButtonIcon(@Nullable final Drawable secondButtonIcon) {
            mSecondButtonIcon = secondButtonIcon;
            return this;
        }

        public DualBuilder secondButtonText(@NonNull final String secondButtonText) {
            mSecondButtonText = secondButtonText;
            return this;
        }

        public MultiViewControl build() {
            return new MultiViewControl(this);
        }
}
```

The above would be a builder if i were to have two of these views. The constructor would take the builder variables and use them to construct a layout for each first/second view. The details of how that happens are not the issue, I just want to learn how to build something like this in a flexible way so it can accept 1...n number of views. What kind of a pattern can i use to achieve this? Any code sample would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Google has released a new library called Fluxbox layout which will serve your purpose.

check out this https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

It will add your view dynamically side by side as you expect.

Comment: I would still like to learn more about a pattern that can best fit the above needs. I wanted to limit the usage of any libraries for this if possible

Answer (score 0):

My two pence here...I just came up with this on the fly based on my experience.
So as I see it, your basic view content is an image and a string. If we consider this as an object structure called ViewContent then we can imagine that the Builder takes a composite of ViewContent objects and therefore we can pass 1..n such objects as a composite as input to the Builder object which will then proceed to act upon all these objects and create a layout for you...Hope this helps.